# Will SSRS reports built with Report builder 3.0 run on SSRS 2019?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a report that was built be a former colleague using Report Builder 3.0. The reports are running nicely on SSRS 2008 R2.  We are provisioning a new server since loading the report via HTTPS is interfering with IIS using HTTPS on the same machine.

When we provision the virtual server, we will most likely use the 2019 version of SSRS to host the report as I have a license for it. My question is, will reports built using report builder 3.0 load correctly in the new environment or does the report need to be upgraded to a newer version and if so, how would I go about that?

I'm not super familiar with building the reports. I did manage to update the report to include a few new fields in the database earlier this year. Additionally, How would I go about finding the report on the server so I could move it to the new server?

Comment: If its a single report you should just be able to save it as a .rdl file from the 2008 version and then upload it into the 2019 version. You will need to reconnect the data connections, and in theory some formats/formulas may (but might not - depending on the report) get messed up, but it should be relatively easy. Ive carried out a similar move previously and out of a couple of hundred reports, one or two needed some extensive redesign but most were fine

Comment: It's a report with 13 sub reports. I will do some research to see what I can come up with. I'm glad to know that in theory it should work.